# Updating rvm ruined my entire environment because I ran "get head" instead of "get stable"

Tags: rvm, rvmrc

Let me preface this question that this is occurring in zsh.

I updated rvm to version 1.15.8. I did a force reinstall of all my rubies. Also set the gems back to pristine conditions. Here is a list of the problems I have encountered:

```
# 1.8.7 no longer compiles because it

# Going to a project directory that contains a .rvmrc file now causes this:

__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
__rvm_remove_from_path:11: failed to compile regex: invalid character range
... for thousands of lines with no end.

# Typing "rvm use 1.9.4-p194@mygemset" yields the same result as above.

# And my favorite: 

bundle install

Tells me I need to install gem bundler'

I do it.

bundle install

Still tells me I need to install gem bundler!
```

I wish I knew how to get back to the previous version of rvm. This is a real problem as I have a deadline. Usually I don't even upgrade rvm to avoid these environment problems, but I was following the directions to try to get it to work with Textmate.

Somebody please help.

UPDATE AFTER ANSWER:

2 things.

1) I ran "rvm get head" instead of "rvm get stable". Cut and paste fail.

2) I figured out the 1.8.7 issue. I ran:

```
brew install tcl
```

and:

```
brew install tk
```

I also changed the ownership of all stuff under $HOME/.rvm to be owned by me. Made sure X11 was installed. Then ran:

```
rvm remove 1.8.7-p352
```

and:

```
rvm install 1.8.7-p352
```

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

This should install the previous version.

```
rvm get 1.15.7
```

here's the issue on github https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1095

Comment: this is another problem - but you are right - using stable version solves it, 1.15.8 is also available as stable, you can check it by using `rvm get stable`.